# How to get unique xpath for all the hyperlink dynamically in webpage

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, automation

I have some web page which contains hyperlinks for some word, which also can be repeated. I need to verify the hyperlink for each word, e.g. the word `headache` which is 3 times in that page. After clicking on each headache the same page opens.

Is there any method which can return the XPath for all words `headache` because for the automation i need to click on every `headache` and verify the URL.

I could write the XPath manually but what if there are a lot of `headache` words on same page which have the hyperlink?

Comment: Your code trials and the relevant `HTML` please.

Comment: What are you expecting this tool/method to do automatically that you can't do manually by hand creating a locator that finds all the links that contain "headache"?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this xpath = `//a[text()='headache']` or  find with linkText `driver.findElements(By.linkText("headache"))`

```
List<Webelement> ele = driver.findElements(By.linkText("headache"))

    for(Webelement link: ele){

    link.click();

     // other operation 

    }
```

Comment: Hi Ankur, I have tried with this xpath --> driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'headache')]")) which is also give the id that contains "headache". but the problem is that there are 3 headache word,and for each headache same xpath id using then how we can perform click operation because it required unique xpth (location) to perform click operation and what i am using xpath it give a collectively xpath for all word headache.

Comment: You can check my ans i have modified it.

Answer (score 0):

In xpath you have to declare type of element for example:
`driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//link[text()='headache']")).forEach(WebElement::click)`

Also if you need just to check the link is correct you can use Rest Assured library and send get requests by http.